# Get data from API and using storage of Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I create a news application by getting data from my JSON API and I would simply like to store my data in Ionic's storage and display what's in storage when the user no longer has an internet connection.

Currently, I retrieve my data with the HttpClient and return an Observable .

I can store them in the storage and display it. But I'm not sure that my life cycle is working properly and I don't know if what I did is good.

ArticleService :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Platform} from "ionic-angular";
import {ArticleCard} from "../classes/ArticleCard";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {IArticleCard} from "../interfaces/IArticleCard";

@Injectable()
export class ArticlesService {

  urlArticlesCards: string = "https://mylink";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public platform: Platform) {

  }

  getAlaUneCards(): Observable<IArticleCard[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.urlArticlesCards)
      .map(res => {
        return res.map(article => {
          return new ArticleCard(
            article.id,
            article.image,
            article.titre,
          );
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Interface :

```
export interface IArticleCard {
  results: {
    id: number;
    image: string;
    titre: string;
  }[]
}
```

ArticleCard :

```
export class ArticleCard {
  id: number;
  image: string;
  titre: string;

  constructor(id: number, image: string, titre: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.image = image;
    this.titre = titre;
  }
}
```

Home :

```
  observable$: Observable<IArticleCard[]>;
  tabCards: Array<Object>= [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private articleService: ArticlesService, private storage: Storage) {}

  ionViewWillEnter() {

    this.observable$ = this.articleService.getAlaUneCards();

    this.observable$.subscribe(cards => {

      if(cards){
        this.storage.set('alaune_cards', cards);
      }

      this.storage.get('alaune_cards').then((card) => {
        this.tabCards = card;
      })

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of some simple improvements:

1) You don't need to re-grab what you just stored in subscribe method. You can just set `this.tabCards = card;` inside the `if (cards) {` branch.

2) I'd only suggest storing a finite amount of data, perhaps the last 50 articles? Anything past that can be grabbed historically from the GET endpoint.

3) If your goal is to display many articles in a list, I highly suggest implementing infinite scroll https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/ . See if you can make your urlArticlesCards GET endpoint pageable. This will make your app perform better overall.

Comment: You're right, I am currently collecting 137 cards via my JSON API, if one day I have 1000 cards the application will be very heavy. So I have to recover the last 20 for example and when the user scroll, the virtual scroll will load the next 20?

Comment: Sorry! When talking about dynamically loading data, I meant to say InfiniteScroll: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/

Comment: Thank you for your help but it not working :/ the infinitescroll not displayed the 10 next articles after the chargement.. https://pastebin.com/XhyR98HG

Comment: Try to figure out where it's failing using some console log statements. See if doInfinite() is getting called.

Comment: My console.log("=== doInfinite subscribe ==="); is displayed in the console and the function to get my articles is called

Comment: I see you have a method called resolve() that looks undefined. According to the documentation you should pass in the $event to the doInfinite method, and use `infiniteScroll.complete();` when done.

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: There's two things I can think of that are happening:
1) The infinite scroll doesn't know it's been updated. Something's wrong with the implementation and I think the best thing to do is look at sample code.
2) For some reason Angular's not picking up changes. After the data's added into the array, try `import { ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';` into the file and `ApplicationRef.tick()` on the push.

Good luck!

Comment: the table fills up well with the 10 new articles, it is in the template that they are not displayed